# MbUnit's row attribute in NUnit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, mbunit

While reading an Asp.Net MVC code sample that used MbUnit as it's testing framework, I saw that it was possible to run a single test against multiple input possibilities by using a Row attribute, like so:

```
[Test]
[Row("test@test_test.com")]
[Row("sdfdf dsfsdf")]
[Row("sdfdf@.com")]
public void Invalid_Emails_Should_Return_False(string invalidEmail)
{
    ...
}
```

Please I'd like to know if there is an NUnit equivalent of MbUnit's Row attribute , or otherwise an elegant way to achieve this in NUnit. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're after the TestCase attribute

```
[TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
  Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

http://www.nunit.com/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5.7

Comment: +1 - `TestCaseAttribute` leads to much more readable test code when using multiple parameters than using `ValuesAttribute` with `SequentialAttribute`. I'd only use `ValuesAttribute` if I wanted to use some combination other than the one specified by `SequentialAttribute`.

Answer (score 2):

NUnits [Sequential attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=sequential&r=2.5.5) does exactly that.

> The SequentialAttribute is used on a
>   test to specify that NUnit should
>   generate test cases by selecting
>   individual data items provided for the
>   parameters of the test, without
>   generating additional combinations.
>
> Note: If parameter data is provided by
>   multiple attributes, the order in
>   which NUnit uses the data items is not
>   guaranteed. However, it can be
>   expected to remain constant for a
>   given runtime and operating system.
>
> Example The following test will be
>   executed three times, as follows:
>
> MyTest(1, "A")
>    MyTest(2, "B")
>    MyTest(3, null)

```
 [Test, Sequential]
 public void MyTest(
     [Values(1,2,3)] int x,
     [Values("A","B")] string s) 
 {
     ... 
 }
```

Given your example, this would become

```
[Test, Sequential] 
public void IsValidEmail_Invalid_Emails_Should_Return_False(
  [Values("test@test_test.com"
          , "sdfdf dsfsdf"
          , "sdfdf@.com")] string invalidEmail) 
{ 
    ... 
}
```